# jQuery + parseDouble problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, double

I have an AJAX-request that returns a json object containing a few values with two decimals each, but since it's json these values are strings when returned. What I need to do is to perform addition on these values. Just a simple a+b = c, but they concatenate instead becoming ab.

I was hoping I could use parseDouble in jQuery just like I can use parseInt but apparantly I can't. At least not what I've found. So the question remains, is there any way I can add these two string values into a double or float value? Or should I just calculate this on the server side and send the already additioned value back to the browser and jQuery.

Example:

This is what happens
5.60 + 2.20 = 5.602.20

This is what should happen
5.60 + 2.20 = 7.80

Thankful for answers.

Comment: "...but since it's json these values are strings..." -- JSON values don't have to be strings. They can be objects, arrays, strings, numbers (floating point), booleans, or null.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
var c = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
```

Comment: Oh didn't see your comment, just figured it out. Thanks anyway for being helpful. :)

Comment: You could also use the unary operator (+) to convert the strings to numbers. `var c = +(a) + +(b);`